# Error / Rails 4 on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, git, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm developing a rails app on mac by ruby 2.4 and rails 4.2, and am now looking to continue partial development of the app on windows 7 professional (64bit) through git.

Rails and Ruby are successfully installed in the windows but I get the below error when I "rails s" on the terminal. I saw a recommendation that I should downgrade the ruby version to 2.3 to eliminate the error, and I did it by uru, but I still get the same error.

Looking at the error, it seems to be still derived from Ruby24-x64 folder, meaning 2.4. I also saw some recommend the rails version should be 5 but I didn't try this as I have gotten errors by upgrading the rails version in the middle of development of an app before.

Great if anyone could help me out. Thanks.

```
C:\Users\ytk\Desktop\app_clone\appappapp>rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.6 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated

C:\Users\ytk\Desktop\app_clone\appappapp>ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x64-mingw32]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have "too new" (contains backported patches from 2.4) `ruby 2.3`.

You have: `ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859).`

Try for example, `230p0_migw  : ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x64-mingw32]`.  That is first `2.3.0` ruby.  That should not contain any 2.4 patches.

Your second option is to update rails at least to `rails 4.2.8`, then it should probably work even with this patched `ruby 2.3.3p222` version.

Comment: Thanks! 4.2.10 fixed it. Now I got the below error. do you know how to fix this?
ActionView::Template::Error (Permission denied @ unlink_internal - C:/Users/ytk/AppData/Local/Temp/execjs20180223-8856-1raqnzijs):
2: <html>
3: <head>
4: <title>?????? | <%= yield :title %></title>
5: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolink
s-track' => true %>
6: <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => tr
ue %>
7: <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: </head>
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1614266_434560'

Comment: @ymatt That is completely different question.  Anyways, from the error message my guess is that you don't have access or execute rights on your `C:/Users/ytk/AppData/Local/Temp/` directory.  You can fix it by running `TAKEOWN /F <directory> /R /D Y`.  Not enough space to write about the logic here.

Comment: i know its completely different but thanks! i got this one so i guess im really not authorized...? the laptop is provided by the company i work for so they limit some usage.
C:\Users\ytk>takeown /F "full path of folder or drive" /A /R /D Y
ERROR: The current logged on user does not have administrative privileges.

Comment: @ymatt: Well we separate questions here as it is hard to find answers if you solve the issues in comments and for seconds I also try to improve my rating.  You probably have to be administrator.  Try running your **powershell as Administrator**.  If you are not authorized then you have ask Administrators to do it for you OR you have to create yourself a Virtual machine where you can be administrator.

Comment: hi, sorry for the very late reply. the purpose of doing this with windows to be able to continue to work during my long business trip, which i just got back from... and i was successfully working on windows by temporarily deleting the jsexec part in application.html.erb, which seemed like the root of the error. well, thanks a lot for your help anyways.